# vis.js/Javascript/React: Getting groups from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neo4j, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am currently using REACT as my frontend and accessing data from a Neo4j DB.  Also, I am using vis.js to render a timeline of events.  Currently, I am trying to figure out the best way to display my data in groups in the REACT UI.  Most of the vis.js examples that I have seen use static data in the code.  I also reviewed the vis.js documentation but it was not helpful. Heads up I am new to REACT/JS.

Right now, the following code is displaying all the data on the screen.

```
const nArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.Des[0], start: abs.time, title: abs.Trace, end: null, group: 1}))

const groups = ([{id: 1, content: 'Prog'}])

    <div className="timeline">
        <Timeline 
            groups={groups}
            items={nArray}
            options={options}
            container={container}
          />;
    </div>
```

In my DB I have 4 types of nodes and right now they are all being displayed in the one group, `Prog`.  I would like to display the 4 groups of nodes in their own respective groups on the timeline using vis.js but I am not sure how to filter the data using the map function or if that is the best solution. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this really one piece of code or you mixed js and html (jsx?) in one code block?

Comment: It is JSX using REACT.